# Angular 5 Wait until get response from db by restangular

Tags: angular, angular5

Now I'm studying Angular 5, in the project I use restangular. my current task is to get the server response before starting the page. Can anyone help me? thanks in advance
(I have responce and I can read data in compnent, but I need wait respnce in resolver)

```
> service

getRequest(){
...
  return this.restangular.one(url).get()
}

> resolver

readRequest(){
...
  this.service.getRequest().subscribe(data => {
    return data;
})
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a resolver you have to return the observable so the Router can subscribe on it and wait for data to be returned.

1/ you forgot to return the observable
2/ you added a useless subscription on it

so try this :

```
> resolver

readRequest(){
...
  return this.service.getRequest();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is `resolver` , that can be done from the `routes`

```
{ 
    path: 'detail/:id', 
    component: HeroDetailComponent,
    resolve: {
      hero: HeroDetailResolve
    },
},
```

**[For more details read](https://shermandigital.com/blog/wait-for-data-before-rendering-views-in-angular-2/)** And **[This Also](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve)**

Comment: thanks for the answer, but resolver is already in routes.
> resolver

readRequest(){
...
  this.service.getRequest().subscribe(data => {
    return data;
})
}

//router
{ 
    path: 'detail/:id', 
    component: SomeCompnent,
    resolve: {
      item: resolver(class name)
    },
}